# Problem when installing 14.04 in Toshiba Satellite L845

Tags: uefi

I'm new on Ubuntu. I've got a Toshiba L845 (that comes with W8 pre-installed) and after having so many problems I decided to go to Linux.

I do not want to keep W8 (since I can not even start it due to a blue screen error that cost U$S 400 to be fix according to toshiba).

I've been trying to install Ubuntu through USB. I have correctly "burn" the ISO in another computer and have fixed all the UEFI and Secure BIOS issued.

The copy boots perfectly, but on the main menu of the installation when I click on "Install Ubuntu" the computer keeps restarting all the time. It comes up with the Ubuntu installation menu and then it restarts again and again.

Does someone have the same problem? What can I do to fix it? Please consider that I have no access to Windows. I just have my USB stick and the computer.

Comment: It sounds like Ubuntu installation cannot correctly determine the partitions in the hard drive. Can you boot Ubuntu  from USB (use the Try without install option) and open gparted? Take a screenshot of the Gparted showing the HDD partitions. Upload the screenshot in http://imgur.com and add that link to the question above using the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/629430/edit) feature.

Comment: Are you doing a UEFI install or legacy?  What version of the UFEI firmware does your machine have (problem pre 6.60) ?

Comment: How did you post this question?  Do you have access to another computer?  or does "try Ubuntu" just work?  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

The fact that somebody's asking $400 to fix a blue-screen problem in Windows suggests the possibility that the computer has a hardware fault. That's far from certain, though (you haven't said how much diagnosis went into this repair estimate). If I had to guess, I'd say you might have a damaged hard disk. You can check this by running a SMART test, as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04)

You can determine your boot mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` -- if it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. If my bad-disk hypothesis is correct, this detail is irrelevant; but if something else is going on, knowing the boot mode may be important. *Changing* the boot mode might or might not be possible, depending on how you created your USB drive. If it is possible, it will be done by using the firmware's built-in boot manager (typically accessed via a function key as the computer starts) and selecting the appropriate boot option -- the description of the boot medium usually includes "UEFI" to boot in that mode and omits "UEFI" to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

Comment: Hello Rod, Thank you for your answer. Before I tried to boot it, I change it to CSM because otherwise it wouldn't even boot the installer. But now (only after I changed this and I tried to install Ubuntu) when I try to start the PC normally (without the USB stick) it says  "no bootable device insert boot disk and press any key". Any idea of what could be going on? No trouble before with the PC, only stupid Windows blue screens and now this. Cheers!