# Sudden problem when turning on the computer

Tags: 14.04, boot, startup, crash

I installed Ubuntu yesterday, everything was working perfect.

I turned on the computer today and there was a problem with the `/`(whatever it means).

The only thing I can see is the purple screen saying:

> Serious problem have been found when trying to check / hard drive,
>   press I to ignore, S no to mount and M for manually fix...

If I press "I" or "S" it just goes to a black screen and nothing happens, if I press "M" it takes me to a terminal but I don't know what to know.

I am a bit desperate, since I have to use the computer to make a work presentation urgently.

Will I have to install it again? It was sudden, nothing was working wrong before turning the PC off.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Did you ran any terminal commands found in the net, remove any packages? If you used Ubuntu only for 1 day the fastest solution will be to re-install and be more careful. Unless your HDD is dead.

Comment: The only thing I might have done was deleting the software center (it was not working) so I tried to install it again (and was still not working). Is there any way to check what's going on? Also, when I start the computer, it goes first to a menu to chose the OS (I only have Ubuntu installed).

Comment: Did you ever turn the computer off/on ? If not, then ubuntu wasn't properly installed. Does the live-cd/-usb still work? If so, can you aacces your hard-disk? Is so, run the gnome-tools to analyze your disk.

Comment: The software center wasn't working? What exactly didn't work? How much OS's can you choose between when the computer is turned on?

Comment: It didn't open, no matter what I did it just wouldn't open. I can only chose Ubuntu, Ubuntu advance options and Ubuntu Recovery Mode. None of them works actually, all takes me to the same error (some of them in graphic way and other just with the terminal).

Comment: First try if the live-cd/-usb is still working. If so, try the disc-tools to check whether your drive is still ok. Which version of ubuntu has been installed? Try to open the software-center in the live-mode. Check if all other programs are working. Also you can test if your installation-medium is ok.

Comment: The USB from which I installed it it's working. I installed 14.04 on a Toshiba Satellite L845. Everything works OK from the live mode. Now when I start it again, it doesn't even take me to the screen, it only stays on the purple screen and nothing happends.

Comment: did you format your HDD partition table according to this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: Sorry I don't understand anything in the table. This is my only OS, so I just selected the default partition during the installation. There were three partitions, but I don't know how much space was for each. I just click in the default installation and everything worked perfectly until I turned on today.

Comment: Given this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/629430/problem-when-installing-14-04-in-toshiba-satellite-l845 something seems to be wrong with your hardware. First of all, using the live-usb, try  gparted, remove all partitions and reformat your drive into ext4. Use the disc-analyzer to check if your drive is ok. If so, start installing.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments responding to this question, I am also
of the mind that it is a hardware issue. First, the problem showed
up so quickly, and the OS is not able to find the root partition
(/ - equivalent to C:\ in Windows). There are almost certainly 
Hard Disk problems. It may be possible to correct them with the 
instructions given by the last commenter (Bernard Decock?).
  If you are in a time crunch with the work presentation there
may be a way to deal with that and then spending the time to correct
the PC. If the liveUSB will boot and give you access to software
that is needed for your work, you might be able to save your work
to remaining free space on the USB stick. If no space on that stick,
see if a 2nd USB stick can be seen and save to that. 
  If this would allow you to focus on the presentation and get it done,
great. Do your work and then fix the PC.   Hope this helps.